# How to track javascript event in Piwik?

Tags: javascript, matomo

I want to track when user press enter in input box, the user may want to press enter multiple times, In [Piwik documentation](https://piwik.org/docs/event-tracking/) there is info to use

```
trackEvent(category, action, [name], [value])
```

but example say to use:

```
_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Documentary', 'Play', 'Thrive']);
```

should I use both or one of them, if so which one?

```
function keypress(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    trackEvent("Events", "enter");
    _paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Events', 'enter']);
  }
}
```

or put _paq.push in my tracking snippet (next to other _paq.push) and only use trackEvent in my event, in [Piwik Book](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/piwik-tracking-user-interactions) there is info to use

```
piwikTracker.setCustomVariable
```

which one can I use to track javascript events?

Comment: Wow the documentation is really confusing. I would opt for the `_paq.push` option.

Comment: I'd definitely go with `_paq.push` as it also works if piwik.js hasn't finished loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the documentation seems confusing but, in fact, there are two ways of defining a Piwik tracker:

- **Option 1**: use the "_paq" variable and pushing events as arrays (more documentation here: https://developer.piwik.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide).
- **Option 2**: use the "Piwik.getTracker" or "Piwik.getAsyncTracker" function which will return a tracker variable (more documentation here: https://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/tracking-javascript).

So, to sum up, the main difference between using _paq.push() or yourTracker.trackEvent() is how you define the tracker.

Personally, I would use the second option as it doesn't expose a clear global variable (_paq), reducing the chance of someone trying to track undesired things from the console.

Comment: The documentation really does seem poor: "Piwik.getAsyncTracker(optionalPiwikUrl, optionalPiwikSiteId) - get the internal instance of the Tracker used for asynchronous tracking" - what does that mean though, and why would I want one? And what are the optional url and site ids...?